# Using QR code on my stellar account with memo

Tags: transactions

We are making an exchange so in order to give new customer an address to deposit we give him "generated address", but it is actually a random id that will be used as a memo. Problem is - on other cryptocurrencies we use the new address we gave him to be in the QR code. Now it is not really an address but a memo. So how can we solve this matter?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a federated address instead?

Comment: What do you mean? What is the difference between this and using the memo?

Comment: A federated address is a way to give the user a human readable way of dealing with accounts and memos. They can use something like "username*domain.tld", and the wallet will go ask for the account + memo from a federation server that you are hosting on "domain.ltd".

Comment: I have checked this , but still, I do not understand how to use this in the Qr code. And what is the difference between this and using regular address with memo attached?

Comment: It would be instead of a qr code. The difference is that the user wouldn't have to input a memo in their wallet. You'd be surprised how many users miss this even when it is spelled out in bold letters on the exchange website.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if implemented in common wallets but this should be the way to go:

https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0007.md

Comment: SEP-007 doesn't work well in a QR code setting, because of the potential size of the data